# commonモジュールをimportしたい

Tags: python, python3, 深層学習

「ゼロから作るディープラーニング」という本を読んで勉強しています。
読み進めていくとcommonというモジュールをインポートすることになるのですが、ここで以下のエラーが発生します。

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

commonモジュールというものをインストールしようとしたのですがそもそもこれ自体一般公開されているものではないらしく、インストールできませんでした。
また、githubにはオライリー公式のcommonモジュールのファイルがあったのですが、このファイルはモジュールとして使うことはできるのでしょうか？できるのであればやり方を教えていただきたいです。

【ゼロから作るディープラーニング　ソースコード】
https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch

Answer (score 1):

参照先のリポジトリに`common`というフォルダがあって、それを`import`するようになっています。

例えば`ch06/weight_init_compare.py`の2から5行目に以下の行があり、これが`common`を`import`出来るようにするための準備です。

> ```
> import os
> import sys
>
> sys.path.append(os.pardir)  # 親ディレクトリのファイルをインポートするための設定
> ```

上記のコードは、リポジトリのフォルダ構成をそのまま展開して使用することを前提にしています。

貴方が何か新しいことを行いたい場合、上記のリポジトリを展開したフォルダの`ch01`から`ch08`があるのと同じ階層に自分で何かのフォルダ(例えば`sample01`等)を作って、自分で作成したソースコードをそのフォルダ内に格納し、上記のコードを`common`を`import`する前に挿入すれば良いでしょう。

そうしたフォルダ構成を同様に保つことはせずに済ませたい場合は、上記コードの`os.pardir`の部分を、展開した`common`の親フォルダを絶対パスで指定すれば同等の事が出来ます。

仕様については以下を参照してください。
[6.1.2. モジュール検索パス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)
[6.2. 標準モジュール](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules)

---

Jupyter-lab/notebook系の作業フォルダがスクリプト/ノートブックファイルの存在するフォルダと別になっていることもある開発環境の場合、上記方法だと上手くいかないこともあります。
それは`os.pardir`が`'..'`という文字列定数なので、それは現在の作業フォルダの親フォルダを示すものだからです。
[os.pardir](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.html#os.pardir)

> 親ディレクトリを参照するためにオペレーティングシステムで使われる文字列定数です。 POSIX と Windows では `'..'` になります。 os.path からも利用できます。

参照先リポジトリのIssuesにこんな記事がありました。
[sys.path.append(os.pardir)がうまく行かず、os.pardirのところにフルパスを指定したところ動きました #25](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch/issues/25)
質問者の環境はmacosですがコンソールのようなので参考程度でしょうか。

例えばスクリプトファイル自身のパスを取得出来ればそこから親フォルダを取得する方法があります。
[Pythonで実行中のスクリプトのパスを取得する: __file__, os.path.abspath, os.path.dirname, os.path.basename](https://yu-nix.com/blog/2021/7/20/python-path-get/)
[Pythonで親ディレクトリの絶対パスを取得](https://qiita.com/Amayarielu/items/56d7f5e74ee25bb8d234)

ただしどうもJupyter-lab/notebook系でノートブックファイルのパスを取得する標準的な方法は無さそうな感じです。
でもこちらにそのためのパッケージを自分で作ったこんな記事が見つかったので、試してみてはどうでしょう？
[[Jupyter] 実行中のipynbファイルが自分のパスを取得できるパッケージを作った](https://qiita.com/kzm4269/items/7f79ac40cf8f30e4afa3)

あるいはこんな記事もありますが、ノートブックを色んなフォルダに分けたい場合は向いて無いかもしれません。
[JupyterLabのホームディレクトリを変更する方法](https://sawalabo.com/210318-jupyterlab-home-dir/)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます　言い忘れましたが、今回起きたエラーはjupyterlabでの話で、機種はmacです　質問文に全て書いておくべきでした、伝えるのが遅くて申し訳ございません　ch01からch08が入っているフォルダに自作のソースコードを入れるやり方ですが、こちらはjupyterlabではエラーが出ましたが、ターミナルで実行したらうまく行きました　もう一つのやり方でjupyterlabの方で試してみたのですが、Users/〇〇/Desktop....という風に絶対パスで指定したのですが[SyntaxError: invalid syntax]というエラーが出てしまいました　なにか解決方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: Jupyter系は作業フォルダが別に設定されているので、上記リポジトリのソースのままだと上手くいかないかもしれませんね。絶対パスでSyntaxErrorは`'`や`"`で囲んでいないとかでは？

Comment: ["]をつけたらうまく行きました。ありがとうございました。